# Uniform initialization with {} reporting unused variable

Tags: c++, g++, c++11, uniform-initialization

Compiling this code with g++ 4.7.0 (`-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion -std=c++11`):

```
#include <iostream>  // std::cout, std::endl
#include <string>    // std::string
#include <utility>   // std::move

void out(std::string const &message)
{
   static int count{0};
   std::cout << count++ << " = " << message << std::endl;
}

struct Foo
{
   Foo()                         {out("constructor");}
  ~Foo()                         {out("destructor");}
   Foo(Foo const &)              {out("copy constructor");}
   Foo & operator=(Foo const &)  {out("copy via assignment"); return *this;}
   Foo(Foo &&)                   {out("move constructor");}
   Foo & operator=(Foo &&)       {out("move via assignment"); return *this;}
};

int main()
{
   auto bar{std::move(Foo())};
   out("exiting main");
}
```

...results in the following error:

```
error: unused variable 'bar' [-Werror=unused-variable]
```

I can remove the error by changing the `bar` initialization to any of the following:

```
/* 0 */ auto bar(std::move(Foo()));
/* 1 */ Foo bar{std::move(Foo())};
/* 2 */ Foo bar(std::move(Foo()));
/* 3 */ auto bar = std::move(Foo());
/* 4 */ Foo bar = std::move(Foo());
/* 5 */ auto bar __attribute__((unused)) {std::move(Foo())};
```

Once the `bar` initialization has been changed, the output is *always*:

```
0 = constructor
1 = move constructor
2 = destructor
3 = exiting main
4 = destructor
```

Why does the original `bar` initialization report an unused variable?

Comment: What happens at runtime if you use the "bad" version of the code and compile without `-Werror`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck the **error** turns into a **warning**

Comment: Seems like it's just an unhandled case in the unused variable warning logic. File a bug with gcc.

Comment: I said "at runtime."  I meant please run the program after compiling it without -Werror, and tell us what you see.  Does it do the same as the other versions of the code, or does it print nothing, or what?

Comment: @JohnZwinck My mistake. At runtime, it outputs the same as the other versions.

Comment: FYI: unless it changed in recent versions gcc detection of unused variables relied on optimization passes. Since the optimizations passes applied may be different depending on how the IR (Gimple ?) is generated, and this itself may depend on the how the variable is declared/initialized, I am not too surprised that the new syntax may have some quirks. If you report it, it will probably be fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
auto bar{std::move(Foo())};
```

After this declaration, `bar` is of type `std::initializer_list<Foo>`, which has trivial copy/move operations and destructor.  Your other declarations

```
auto bar(std::move(Foo()));
Foo bar{std::move(Foo())};
Foo bar(std::move(Foo()));
auto bar = std::move(Foo());
Foo bar = std::move(Foo());
```

declare `bar` as `Foo` or `Foo&&`, which suppresses the warning since it has nontrivial special member functions.

You generally don't want braced initialization with `auto` unless you specifically intend to create a `std::inializer_list` object.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I was erroneously assuming that GCC would use `Foo` as the type when it actually has no reason to.

Comment: In fact, I tried `auto bar{5}; cout << typeid(bar) << endl;` and it output `St16initializer_listIiE`, so you're definitely correct!

Answer (score 2):

Well, `bar` *is* unused. You may want to file a defect for the compiler as this seems to errornously go undetected in the other situations.

Comment: `bar` is unused, but I thought the compiler didn't report unused variable warnings for non-trivial types.

Comment: Whatever the compiler uses to produce warnings is up to the compiler! My personal position is that I want all unused variables flagged when I ask for unused variables to be flagged. In my toolkit I have a simple function template for the cases where I mean objects to be unused: `template <typename T> void use(T const&) {}`.